# How can I create index for a table with combined primary key?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I use MYSQL to create a table with combined primary key. For example, col_a and col_b are used together as the key. I will use col_a and col_b to get a row often, and also will use col_a or col_b separately to query some rows.

My questions is, how will I create the index for it?  Will I need only one composite index, or three indexes with two indexes for the separated columns?

I think MYSQL will create the index for primary key. But will it create a composite index for (col_a, col_b), or create an index for each column?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Multi-Column Indexes**

For a multi-column index, the index works from left to right.

Given your primary key:

```
(col_a, col_b)
```

Here are the cases where it can be used:

- **col_a**: **YES**. The index can be utilized when searching on col_a, since starting from left to right, col_a is the first column.
- **col_a & col_b**: **YES**. When searching on col_a, and col_b, the index can also be utilized because starting from left to right, it's col_a, then col_b.
- **col_b:**: **NO**. When searching only for col_b, the index can't be used because the first column in the index is col_a, and we can't skip over columns.

Given a larger index like this:

```
(col_a, col_b, col_c)
```

- **col_a**: **YES**
- **col_a & col_b**: **YES**
- **col_a & col_b & col_c**: **YES**
- **col_a & col_c**: **NO**. Can't skip over col_b in the index.
- **col_b:**: **NO**. Can't skip col_a.
- **col_c:**: **NO**. Can't skip col_a.
- **col_b & col_c**: **NO**. Can't skip over col_a in the index.

**Covering Indexes**

To utilize an index as a ["covering" index](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/11/23/covering-index-and-prefix-indexes/), the left-to-right pattern still applies.

Given the index `(col_a, col_b)`, you can select both col_a and col_b, but search only on col_a (or col_a and col_b), and MySQL can use the index both for the search and for retrieving the data because col_a and col_b are both in the index. This saves a trip to the actual row data, since the values are stored in the index.

Given the index `(col_a, col_b, col_c)`, you could not SELECT col_a and col_c if you were searching only on col_a and be able to use the covering index to return col_c, since you can't skip over col_b in the index. Instead, MySQL would visit the actual table data. However, you could SELECT col_a and col_c and use it as a covering index if you were searching on both col_a and col_b.

**Primary Keys in "Covering" Indexes**

Every secondary index has the primary key included in the index.

A single column index, as it relates to a covering index, can be thought of as a multi-column index in the following pattern. Given the primary key `(col_a, col_b)`, a single column index on col_b, really looks like this `(col_b)(col_a, col_b)`.

Given the above single column index, you could still select col_a and col_b, and search on col_b, and the index could be used as a covering index. Since the primary key includes col_a, MySQL could still use the index to return both columns without having to hit the actual table data.

**What if I want to search on col_b?**

Given the primary key `(col_a, col_b)`, if you want to search on just col_b, you should add a single column index on col_b. As described above, it can still be used as a covering index if you are returning col_b and col_a.

Comment: great explaination

Answer (score 3):

The composite primary key index on (col_a, col_b) will take care of situations where you are querying on both columns or querying on only col_a. For queries on only col_b, you'll need a separate index.

Comment: To clarify, for the col_b index, create the index on just col_b, not (col_b, col_a). The primary key is already part of the index, which includes col_a, and will serve as a "covering index".